# Step through form as all inputs are completed in a row

Tags: jquery, dynamicform

-- [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sKsEw/1/) --

I'm designing a form that acts like a wizard, walking the user through each input, and not allowing them to continue until all inputs have been addressed.

I want to show the next row in the table *if and only if* all inputs in the current row have either been filled out or checked. Rows may contain any number of text inputs, checkboxes, or radio groups.

Here's my current code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>

        <td><input type="radio"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display:none">
        <td><input type='radio'></td>

        <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="display:none">
        <td><input type='text'></td>

        <td><input type='text'></td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

---

```
function refreshCascadingLists() {
    // Get an array of tr's
    // Loop thorugh each and see if it should be shown based on it's predecessors status
    var prevHadUnselected = false;
    $("table tr").next("tr").each(function(curIdx, curEntity) {
        if (prevHadUnselected) {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        } else {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }

        prevHadUnselected = false;
        $(this).find(":input").each(function(curSelIdx, curSelEntity) {
            if ($(curSelEntity).val() == "" && $(curSelEntity).not(":checked")) 
                prevHadUnselected = true;
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input").bind('keyup change', function() {
        refreshCascadingLists();
    });
});​
```

---

This will show the next row when the user types into the text box in the first row, but they should also have to check the radio button. Furthermore, it's displaying ALL of the rows in the table, instead of just the next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/JGkwj/):

```
function refreshCascadingLists($tr) {
    var all_filled = true;
    $tr.find(':input').each(function() {
        if($(this).is('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]')) {
            if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                all_filled = false;    
            }
        } else if($(this).val() == '') {
            all_filled = false;
        }
    });

    var $next_tr = $tr.next('tr');    
    if(all_filled) {
        if(!$next_tr.is(':visible')) {
            $next_tr.fadeIn(function() {
                refreshCascadingLists($(this));                    
            });    
        }
    } else {
        $tr.nextAll('tr').hide();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input").bind('keyup change', function() {
        refreshCascadingLists($(this).closest('tr'));
    });
});​
```

Most of the function could actually be golfed down quite a bit, but I wrote it like that so you can easily see what it is doing.

Comment: This works, but in my actual form (I stripped down the situation for the question), it seems to be getting caught on the second row. Thoughts? http://jsfiddle.net/4T9pc/2/

Comment: @jon: Think it's the way I'm calculating radio buttons... mmm.

Comment: Is it because it's expecting the whole group to be checked?

Comment: @Jon Yes, try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/JGkwj/1/ - it gets a little more complicated if you can potentially have multiple groups of radios in one row, that version should allow for that.

Comment: Works! There are some odd conditions throughout, so I might just alter it to require only one of the inputs each row to be filled/checked. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @Jon: yeah going through your form it seems what I gave you is not quite there considering your intentions, but hopefully it gets you started. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here `$("table tr").next("tr").each(...`

You are selecting ALL next rows for each row in `$("table tr")`. To fix move the `.next("tr")` inside `each()`.

Here is simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/sKsEw/8/)

Comment: Before the function() { ... } ? So  $("table tr").each(next("tr") function(curIdx, curEntity) { ... } ? That seems odd.

Comment: Don't you mean remove it completely? it isn't needed inside the each, the each will automatically go to the next one on the next iteration...

Comment: No no no... You have to call `next()` on your `curEntity` or `this` (which are the same in that context) inside the function you are passing to `each()`.

Comment: Could you edit the Fiddle? Between you and Kevin, I'm a little lost.

Comment: @Jon updated my answer. Note that I reversed lookup from next to prev for simplicity.

Comment: If I empty out the first textbox after getting all the way to the third row your fiddle doesn't behave properly.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino it does now